# SQLAlchemy class method for subquery

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

I have a table of time series data that I frequently need to get records where the date is equal to the max date in the table. In SQL this is easily accomplished via subquery, i.e.:

```
SELECT * from my_table where date = (select max(date) from my_table);
```

The model for this table would look like:

```
class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = Column(Date)
```

And I can accomplish the desired behavior in SQLAlchemy with two separate queries, ie:

```
maxdate = session.query(func.max(MyTable.date)).first()[0]
desired_results = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.date == maxdate).all()
```

The problem is that I have this subquery sprinkled everywhere in my code and I feel it is an inelegant solution. Ideally I would like to write a class property or custom comparator that I can stick in the model definition, so that I can compress the subquery into a single line and reuse it constantly, something like:

`session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.date == MyTable.max_date)`

I have looked through the SQLAlchemy [docs](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/extensions/hybrid.html) on this but haven't come up with anything that works. Does anybody have neat a solution for this kind of problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For posterity, here is the solution I came up with

```
from sqlalchemy.sql import func
from sqlalchemy import select   

class MyTable(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'my_table'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key = True)
    date = Column(Date)
    maxdate = select([func.max(date)])

desired_results = session.query(MyTable).filter(MyTable.date == MyTable.maxdate).all()
```